# golang and python thrift communication

Tags: python, go, thrift

I am using Thrift.
Here is the thrift file:

```
namespace py hello
namespace go hello

service Hello{ 
    string helloString(1:string para) 
}
```

And I then generate the python and golang code

```
thrift -gen py Hello.thrift
thrift -gen go Hello.thrift
```

Python server code: py-server.py

```
import socket
import sys
sys.path.append('./gen-py/')

from hello import Hello
from hello.ttypes import *

from thrift.transport import TSocket
from thrift.transport import TTransport
from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol
from thrift.server import TServer

class HelloHandler:
    def helloString(self, msg):
        ret = "helloString Received: " + msg
        print ret
        return msg


handler = HelloHandler()
processor = Hello.Processor(handler)
transport = TSocket.TServerSocket("127.0.0.1", 19090)
tfactory = TTransport.TBufferedTransportFactory()
pfactory = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocolFactory()

server = TServer.TSimpleServer(processor, transport, tfactory, pfactory)

print "Starting thrift server in python..."
server.serve()
```

and i can run well:

```
$ python py-server.py 
Starting thrift server in python...
```

And my client is writen by golang, go-client.go:

```
package main

import (
    "./gen-go/hello"
    "fmt"
    "git.apache.org/thrift.git/lib/go/thrift"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    transportFactory := thrift.NewTFramedTransportFactory(thrift.NewTTransportFactory())
    protocolFactory := thrift.NewTBinaryProtocolFactoryDefault()
    transport, err := thrift.NewTSocket(net.JoinHostPort("127.0.0.1", "19090"))
    fmt.Println(1)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "error resolving address:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    useTransport := transportFactory.GetTransport(transport)
    client := hello.NewHelloClientFactory(useTransport, protocolFactory)
    fmt.Println(2)
    if err := transport.Open(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(3)
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "localhsot:19090", " ", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer transport.Close()
    fmt.Println(4)
    r1, e1 := client.HelloString("lalalalalalalallalaal")
    fmt.Println(5)
    fmt.Println("Call->", r1, e1)
}
```

But it can't run, it output, and it can not stop normally

```
$ go run go-client.go 
1
2
4
```

and the server do not receive any message.

Is there any problem in my golang code?

---

if i write a client by python , it can run well..

```
import socket
import sys
sys.path.append('./gen-py/')

from hello import Hello
from thrift import Thrift
from thrift.transport import TSocket
from thrift.transport import TTransport
from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol

try:
    transport = TSocket.TSocket('127.0.0.1', 19090)
    transport = TTransport.TBufferedTransport(transport)
    protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(transport)
    client = Hello.Client(protocol)
    transport.open()

    print "client - helloString"
    msg = client.helloString("lalalalalla")
    print "server - " + msg


    transport.close()

except Thrift.TException, ex:
    print "%s" % (ex.message)

$ python py-client.py 
client - helloString
server - lalalalalla
```

Comment: Thrift version 0.9.2   go version go1.4.2 darwin/amd64   Python 2.7.5

Answer (score 0):

`transportFactory := thrift.NewTFramedTransportFactory(thrift.NewTTransportFactory())`

please change `NewTFramedTransportFactory` to `NewTBufferedTransportFactory`, just like `transportFactory := thrift.NewTBufferedTransportFactory(1024)`, thanks.